# Iterating comma separated list in views

Tags: django

How do you loop over a values from a checkbox within a view.

This is what I have tried so far:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
        form = SomeForm(request.POST)
        # Check we have valid data before saving trying to save.
        if form.is_valid():
            data = form.cleaned_data
            groups = data['thischeckbox']
            for item in groups:
                print(item)
```

But this gives a **KeyError**.

Comment: try: `groups = data.getlist('thischeckbox', [])`

Comment: that give me 'dict' object has no attribute 'getlist'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SomeForm(request.POST)
    # Check we have valid data before saving trying to save.
    if form.is_valid():
        data = form.cleaned_data
        groups = data['thischeckbox'].split(",")
        for item in range(len(groups))
            print(groups[item])
```